# How to use Qt Creator with Visual C++ compiler on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I installed Visual Studio 2008, Qt 4.8 libraries for vs2008 and Qt add in. I can build Qt projects in VS2008. But it's very inconvenient for me. When I open Qt project in Qt creator it can't compile because can't find qmake.

So, how to build projects using Qt Creator on windows.

Comment: Why can't you use the MinGW they provide? Also Visual Studio 2008 is really old..

Comment: why don't you try to google this, for example? http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-267324.html
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.1/creator-project-qmake.html

Comment: The best think that you can do it to use separated, because Qt Creator is an IDE for At. Also take a look on official web page and see how can be install on windows.

Comment: I can't use MinGW because project needs VS headers.

Comment: Did you try to find qmake.exe using explorer? It has to be there, because the Qt add in needs it also. Then you can just point to it in Qt Creator's settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help its having easy steps with some solution of errors that one may encounter during installation  http://qtitkvtkhelp.blogspot.in/2012/11/qt-installation-prerequisite-1.html

Answer (score 4):

Use CMake to build your software. With CMake you can:

- -Build your project on a continuous integration server
- Compile with different compilers (Microsoft, gcc, clang) to get additional static checking.
- Open the top level CMakeLists.txt with creator as a project file.
- Have CMake create Visual Studio project files.

If you want to fix Creator only: 
Qt Creator needs to know where your Qt installation is. Choose the green Qt symbol in the settings menu, klick Qt Version and enter the path to qmake. Then Qt Creator should be ready to go.

Comment: That is a good idea in general. But if for some reason you are stuck with msvc project the Qt Creator is kind of alpha quality there